# Useless queries after migrating to Hibernate 6

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-6.x

I tried to migrate a spring boot project to the newest version. Which included an upgrade to hibernate 6. I have done that before and never had an issue like this. I use spring-data-jpa Repositories with an MSSQL Database. After the Update close to all of my queries are broken. I debugged into it and found out, the JPQL looks fine. But somewhere on the way to TransactSQL something mysterious is happening.
I'd like to show you three of the problems I faced.

**Problem Nr. 1**

```
@Entity public class Gender {
    ...
}

@Entity public class Person {
    @ManyToOne public Gender gender;
    @Embedded public Details details;
}
```

With something as simple as this. I expected to see `select ... from Person` or maybe even `select ... from Person p left join Gender g on ...` if Gender is fetched eagerly. But what i got was

```
select ... from Person p1 left join Person p2 on p1.id = p2.id left join Gender g on ...
```

which works but it is rather useless to have that second join on Person.

**Problem Nr. 2**

resultPerson.details is null although the query actually returned values for the columns inside Person.details.

**Problem Nr. 3**

A more complex query I wrote myself now joins stuff in the wrong order:

```
select Person p1
left join Something s1 on s2.somethingId = s1.somethingId
left join SomethingElse s2 on ...
```

**Question**

All these queries worked fine before the upgrade and haven't been touched during the upgrade. All the errors are so diverse, that I don't even know where to start looking. I don't expect you to solve my problems. I'm just asking for hints. Hope anybody has seen this before.

Comment: Create a minimal reproducer for each problem and create an issue with the Hibernate team. Make sure to search for existing issues, before creating new ones.

Comment: It isn't that easy. I can't even isolate the problem. My minimum reproductions work just fine. I am just asking for some hints on where to look for. Embeddable instantiation, implicit joins, eager fetching. Something like that.